# When I use mat-input and mat-field in same row, and add mat-chip, these 2 fields not remain in same line

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, mat-input

I have two three input in the same row. The first two are mat-input, and the third one is mat-chip, all in same line. When I add mat-chip, this field goes down, and alignment from first two field does not remain same, in one line.

[image]
[image]

my code is something like this.

```html
<mat-card-content *ngIf="addProductForm.controls['is_product_variant'].value == 1">
  <div formArrayName="variants" class="bottomMargin fancyscroll" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; height:120px;">
    <div *ngFor="let unitproductVariants of addProductForm.controls.variants.controls; let i=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="1%" fxLayoutAlign="center">
          <div fxFlex="20">
            <mat-form-field fxFlex="100%">
              <mat-label>Variant SKU<span *ngIf="i == 0">*</span></mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Variant SKU" formControlName="variant_sku" autocomplete="off">
              <mat-error *ngIf="unitproductVariants.controls['variant_sku'].hasError('required')">
                Please enter sku</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div fxFlex="25">
            <mat-form-field fxFlex="100%">
              <mat-label>Variant Name<span *ngIf="i == 0">*</span></mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="Variant Name" formControlName="variant_name" autocomplete="off">
              <mat-error *ngIf="unitproductVariants.controls['variant_name'].hasError('required')">
                Please enter name</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div fxFlex="55">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" fxFlex="100%">
              <mat-chip-list #barcodeList>
                <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of unitproductVariants?.controls?.barcode?.value" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeBarcode(item,i)">
                  {{item}}
                  <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                </mat-chip>
                <input placeholder="Enter Barcodes" class="margin-zero" [matChipInputFor]="barcodeList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addBarcode($event,i)" formControlName="barcodes" autocomplete="off">
                <mat-icon matSuffix class="auto_icon" (click)="auto_generate_barcode(i)">text_format</mat-icon>
              </mat-chip-list>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <!-- <div fxFlex="5">
                      <button type="button" mat-button color="primary" class="cancel-button" (click)="auto_generate_barcode(i)">Auto</button>
                    </div> -->
          <!-- delete button -->
          <div fxFlex="5" fxLayoutAlign="center">
            <button class="marginTop" *ngIf="addProductForm.controls.variants.controls.length > 1 && i!=0" mat-icon-button (click)="removeUnit(i)">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                      </button>
          </div>
          <!-- delete button -->
        </div>

        <!-- <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap fxLayoutGap="3.5%" fxLayoutAlign="center">
                    <div fxFlex="90%">
                      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" fxFlex="100">
                        <mat-chip-list #barcodeList>
                            <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of unitproductVariants?.controls?.barcode?.value"
                              [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeBarcode(item,i)">
                              {{item}}
                              <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                            </mat-chip>
                            <input placeholder="Enter Barcodes" class="margin-zero" [matChipInputFor]="barcodeList"
                              [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                              (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addBarcode($event,i)" formControlName="barcodes"
                              autocomplete="off">
                          </mat-chip-list>
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div fxFlex="10%">
                      <button type="button" mat-button color="primary" class="cancel-button" (click)="auto_generate_barcode(i)">Auto</button>
                    </div>
                  </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-card-content>
```